# How do I limit extra HTTP requests and share responses for requests that are made within a set period?

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6

I need to limit how many times a HTTP request can be made in a certain time period. So, for example, the first call made will send a request but **if another request is made within the set time period (3 seconds) then I want to share the response rather than making another HTTP request**. Whereas, if the second request is made after the set time period then just send a new request.

My current understanding (feel free to correct me as I'm probably wrong) is that:

- debounceTime wont help as it delays the first request by a certain
  time period. Whereas I don't want to delay the first request, I want it to be sent straight away and any future requests made in the set time period to share the response.
- throttleTime wont help as it just delays the second request
- shareReplay wont help as all future requests are shared even if they
  are made 10 minutes later

What I'm looking for is a mix between throttleTime and shareReplay where I can configure a time period and the first request is sent straight away but any future requests made within the time period just share the response of the first one. After the time period has finished (3 seconds) the next request will send a new HTTP request.

Comment: ```setInterval``` ?

Comment: Have you tried `shareReplay(1, 3000)`?

Comment: Here is how i would have implemented.

1) Create a HTTP Intercepter using HttpClient Service.
2) Will maintain a state object with Url/RequestID, LastAccessedTime properties.
3) For Every HTTP Call, will check with currentdatetime and URL. If diff is less than 10, get the HTTP response from Service cache object or Local DB.
    - If diff is greater than 10/new request, will Hit the API and save the Response in cache/local DB.